# Why does a:visited {background-color: only work if used with a:link?

Tags: css

From my understanding :visited styles links that have been visited and :link styles links. I noticed that you cant set the background-color with :visited unless you also set a background-color with :link, why is this?? This leads me to think they are different, if so how are different, other then one styles the links and the other visited links?
for example:

https://jsfiddle.net/kk1ouqvc/11/

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">
  wikipedia
</a>

/***
a:visited{
    background-color: red;//doesnt work
     }
 **/

 /***
 a:visited{
      background-color: red;// works
 }
 a:link{
      background-color: blue;
 }
***/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a answer  from https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/visited/ that helped me to understand some times ago. You have to set a background-color on element before it has beeing visited

> There’s also an “anomaly” related to the background-color applied to a link using :visited: the background color in the :visited state won’t be applied to the link unless an actual “real” background color is applied to the link prior to its visited state—that is, in its :link state.